# slimscroll mouse click and scroll issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

I have used slimscoll in my code which work perfectly in firefox.
issue is with chrome when I click on scrollbar and tries to drag it. It selects the entire div or div content around it.
may be its because as mouse get moved out of that slim area of slimscroll and browser recognizing it as a content select.

could you please help me with that ????
here is sample code I am using for slimscroll

```
$('#Div').slimscroll({
    railVisible: true,
    allowPageScroll: false,
    height: '320px'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try addinig a size to make it wider. In Chrome I am not seeing the same issue.

```
$('#Div').slimscroll({
    railVisible: true,
    allowPageScroll: false,
    height: '320px',
    size: '10px'
});
```

documentation has an example like this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I modified the call of attachWheel() in jquery.slimscroll.js to

`attachWheel.apply(this);`

This workes for me.

Comment: not sure why is this down voted. I know if it is because of changing the library and not extending it but the answer is correct and is working.